# How to sort an ElasticSearch index using a field inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, elasticsearch

I need to sort documents in my elastic index using a field inside an array in that document. Document structure looks like this,

```
{
  'name':'xxxxx',
  'comments':[
     {comment: 'xxxxx', 'commentDate':'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'id':1},
     {comment: 'xxxxx', 'commentDate':'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'id':2}
   ]
}
```

What I want to do is sort the documents based on the `commentDate` field to get the documents with latest comments first. So far I've think of keeping separate field inside the document to track the last comment date. So the document becomes,

```
{
  'name':'xxxxx',
  'comments':[
     {comment: 'xxxxx', 'commentDate':'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'id':1},
     {comment: 'xxxxx', 'commentDate':'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'id':2}
   ],
  'lastCommentDate': 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
}
```

I'd like to know whether is this the best way of doing this or is it possible to do this using script sort without changing the index?

I'm using Elastic API for Java and it would be very much appreciated if you can show me how to do this without changing the index. Also, I want to get the sorted data set directly from ES, so sorting after fetching data is not what I'm looking for

Elastic version : 5.1.1

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Amriteya I'm using version 5.1.1

Comment: What is the query that you're running?

Comment: Also, are you setting the mapping of the index before ingesting the data?

Comment: @Amriteya I don't have any custom mapping on the index

Comment: That could be the problem. When you index automatically without setting the mapping, the nested documents don't get mapped properly.

Comment: @Amriteya yeah. that was the issue. Thanks

Comment: Amazing. Happy to help.

Comment: @Amriteya I was going through my questions and noticed that you saved my day with this matter. Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ingesting data without creating a mapping on the index, Elasticsearch will flatten the nested documents.

Elasticsearch does this to speed up the query although it is not suitable in cases like these.

Make sure you create a custom mapping before ingesting the data to be indexed.